# Is there a way to get a refresh token from OAuth2 without user input/verification?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

I've made a script that runs on the Google Ads API. The project on [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com) is configured as "External" and "In Testing".
The script I'm talking about needs to be run daily on a cron job. Issue is, every week I have to get a new refresh token manually, which is unnecessary in my opinion.
So, is there a way to get a new refresh token without needing a user pressing "Continue" and "Accept", i.e. verifying that they allow access to Google Ads?
Or does that only happen when I Publish my app on [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com)?

So far, I either put the refresh token into the script and it works or (in another script) I use the refresh token to cURL into https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token to get an access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking on https://groups.google.com(question and answer is [here](https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/Mn8TgBUxW3Q/m/hcQtEowyBgAJ)), it seems it's impossible for a refresh token to be retrieved without a user confirming access to their Google Ads Account.